# Calcular mediana Array

Tags: javascript

Tengo este array bidimensional que representa las 7 notas de 20 alumnos. Ahora tengo que calcular la media de las terceras notas de cada alumno. Es decir, son 7 notas que representan 7 exámenes distintos, pues ahora quiero calcular la media del examen número 3.

El código es el siguiente:

```javascript
var notas = Array(7,8,7.7,7,98,9,8,7,8,9,7,8,7.7,7,98,9,8,7,8,9,7,8,7.7,7,98,9,8,7,8,9,7,8,7.7,7,98,9,8,7,8,9,7,8,7.7,7,98,9,8,7,8,9,7,8,7.7,7,98,9,8,7,8,9,7,8,7.7,7,98,9,8,7,8,9,7,8,7.7,7,98,9,8,7,8,9,7,8,7.7,7,98,9,8,7,8,9,7,8,7.7,7,98,9,8,7,8,9,7,8,7.7,7,98,9,8,7,8,9,7,8,7.7,7,98,9,8,7,8,9,7,8,7.7,7,98,9,8,7,8,9,7,8,7.7,7,98,9,8,7,8,9);
var i, j, q;

var notas2 = Array(20);
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  notas[i] = Array(7);
}

q = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
    notas2 [i][j] = notas[q];
    q= q+1;
  }
}

console.log(notas2);
```

El problema es que no consigo mi objetivo. Espero que puedan ayudarme.

Comment: un condicional `media_de_3=0; for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) { if(j===2){ media_de_3+=notas[i][j]}}} console.log("la media es: "+ media_de_3/20)`

Comment: @Bryo no entiendo tu comentario

Answer (score 1):

Para empezar el array no tiene dos dimensiones por lo que asumo que cada 7 elementos representan un alumno. Por lo que primero dividimos las 140 notas en bloques de 7 para obtener las 7 calificaciones de los 20 alumnos. Ya que tenemos los 20 bloques buscamos la 3ra calificación y creamos un array para almacenarlas. Por último sumamos todas las calificaciones y dividimos entre el número de elementos para obtener la media.

```js
const notas = [
  7,8,7.7,7,98,9,8,
  7,8,9,7,8,7.7,7,
  98,9,8,7,8,9,7,
  8,7.7,7,98,9,8,7,
  8,9,7,8,7.7,7,98,
  9,8,7,8,9,7,8,
  7.7,7,98,9,8,7,8,
  9,7,8,7.7,7,98,9,
  8,7,8,9,7,8,7.7,
  7,98,9,8,7,8,9,
  7,8,7.7,7,98,9,8,
  7,8,9,7,8,7.7,7,
  98,9,8,7,8,9,7,
  8,7.7,7,98,9,8,7,
  8,9,7,8,7.7,7,98,
  9,8,7,8,9,7,8,
  7.7,7,98,9,8,7,8,
  9,7,8,7.7,7,98,9,
  8,7,8,9,7,8,7.7,
  7,98,9,8,7,8,9
];

const notasPorAlumno = [],
  totalExamenes = 7;

while (notas.length > 0) {
  notasPorAlumno.push(notas.splice(0, totalExamenes));
}

const calificaciones3 = notasPorAlumno.reduce((acc, current) => {
  acc.push(current[2]);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(calificaciones3);
console.log(calificaciones3.length);
console.log(
  calificaciones3.reduce((acc, current) => acc + current, 0) /
    calificaciones3.length
);
```

**Nota:** El proceso de acumular la 3ra nota y luego ocupar esa acumulación para calcular la media pudiera hacerse dentro de un solo `.reduce()`, pero lo coloco en dos para que se observe el procedimiento de "búsqueda" y cálculo.